# filter to retrieve all the JIRA issues where I was mentioned in the last 7 days in a comment

Tags: jira, jql

I'm trying to setup a JIRA filter to find all the mentions of me(currentUser()) in the last 7 days.  I'm close with the search below, but it still gives me all issues that mentioned me AND were updated in the last 7 days.  Which is a lot more. :)  I want all the issues where I was mentioned in the last 7 days in a comment.

```
comment ~ currentUser() AND issueFunction in commented(“after -7d”)
```

Thank-you for your help!

Comment: Also see here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/81845/can-users-that-have-been-mentioned-in-issues-be-queried-by-jql

Answer (score 6):

Did you try something like this query?

```
(text ~ currentUser()) AND updatedDate &gt;= -7d ORDER BY updated DESC
```

It gives me all mentions in the last 7 days. But also mentions in descriptions (found it on the [this blog post](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/06/using-watchers-and-mentions-effectively/)).

Comment: That query doesn't solve the original problem. It returns **all** tickets that have been updated in the last 7 days _regardless_ of _when_ I was mentioned. The requester wanted to query tickets in which he was _mentioned_ within the past 7 days. I don't believe it's possible to filter by the date of mention.

Answer (score 3):

I use something like this:

```
(summary ~ currentUser() OR description ~ currentUser() OR comment ~ currentUser()) AND updatedDate >= -7d
```

Comment: This is all the issues that the current user is mentioned in (at any point in time) that have been updated recently.

Answer (score 0):

The query below will bring you the issues which you were mentioned in anywhere (comments, description, summary etc.) and updated in the last 7 days.

```
text ~ currentUser() AND updated > -7d ORDER BY updatedDate DESC
```

There are no direct queries for now to filter by mention date. Maybe the scripted JQL functions in the link can help in this way.

https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=57999378#ScriptedJQLFunctions-lastComment(commentquery)